# How to correctly assign routes with middleware for user types? Laravel

Tags: laravel

In my project I have 4 user types super admin, admin, director and user. The super admin and admin can see the same pages and have all the same route, the difference between them is distinguishable in the controllers, the director only has 6 routes or about half of the super admin, and the user only sees the dash board.

Right now I'm trying to set up the routes in the web.php but either the super admin, admin works and not the director or the directors routes work and the other two don't. What am I doing wrong?

Middleware SuperAdmin

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    if (auth()->check() && $user->isSuperAdmin()) {
        return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Middleware Admin

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    if (auth()->check() && $user->isAdmin() || $user->isSuperAdmin()) {
        return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Middleware Director

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    if (auth()->check() && $user->isDirector()) {
        return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect('/');
}
```

In the web.php

```
//Auth and login routes
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::resource('/', 'DashController');
    Route::get('/logout')->name('logout')->uses('Auth\LoginController@logout');
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware'], function () {

        //All the routes are in this group
    });

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'App\Http\Middleware\DirectorMiddleware'], function () {

        //Corresponding routes for director here
    });
});
```

In my Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
    'super' => \App\Http\Middleware\SuperAdminMiddleware::class,
    'director' => \App\Http\Middleware\DirectorMiddleware::class,
    //other default ones
];
```

What am I doing wrong, what is the correct way to get those all working and not just one group at a time?

Comment: have you register middleware in kernel?

Comment: @YasinPatel yes

Comment: here in route file you just need to use name of that middleware

Comment: Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'admin'
], function () {
}